# Inspect disabled element in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How do I right click a disable element to inspect it in google chrome?

Do I have to use the "Select an element in the page to inspect it" button

[image]

or is there a way to enable the right click menu even for disabled elements?

Answer (score 1):

I've been also trying to do this, but could not figure it out on Chrome.
This would be helpful for me to inspect the accessibility of disabled buttons (color contrast mainly), but there is no way to do it using the right-click => inspect/select element tools.

If you are using Windows 10 you can try Edge (Chromium), which does support this functionality.